# Use of which : examples correct?

Tags: grammar

> During the time **of which** he kept a record the number of road accidents never rose above a 100.

or

> During the time **in which** he kept a record the number of road accidents never rose above a 100.

Which is the better of these two?

Answer (score 1):

It's more of a question of which preposition to use to effect the meaning you're intending to convey than *which one is better?*

*Keeping a record **of** a particular time is different from *keeping a record **in** that time*, with the latter, not necessarily implying, the record **of** that very time itself.*

Answer (score 0):

During the time in which he kept a record, the number of road accidents never rose above 100.

**Note**

We read "100" as "a hundred" or "one hundred".